# My key down handler function isn't working

Tags: javascript

The problem that im having is that the dog isn't moving, its supposed to go left and right but as i said before, it doesnt respond to key presses.
Also it would be really nice if someone told me how to make it stop at the bottom and not keep moving off the canvas. Thank you!

```js
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var x_pos = 0;
var y_pos = 0;
var MyImg = new Image();
MyImg.src = "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/noto-emoji-animals-nature/96/22215-dog-icon.png";

function MyTimer() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, 456);
  y_pos = y_pos + 1;
  ctx.drawImage(MyImg, 89, y_pos);

  ctx.font = "57px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "GainsBoro"
  ctx.fillText("Myverrynicename", 10, 250)
}

function MyKeyDownHandler(MyEvent) {
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 39 && x_pos + MyImg.width < myCanvas.width) {
    x_pos = x_pos + 7;
  }
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 37 && x_pos > 0) {
    x_pos = x_pos - 7;
  }
}

setInterval(MyTimer, 43);
addEventListener("keydown", MyKeyDownHandler);
```

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title> MD2 </title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id=myCanvas width=456 height=456 style="background-color: green;"> </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Stop at the end the same way that you stop at the right.

Answer (score 1):

You never use your `x_pos`

```js
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var x_pos = 0;
var y_pos = 0;
var MyImg = new Image();
MyImg.src = "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/noto-emoji-animals-nature/96/22215-dog-icon.png";

function MyTimer() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, 456);
  y_pos = y_pos + 1;
  ctx.drawImage(MyImg, x_pos, y_pos);

  ctx.font = "57px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "GainsBoro"
  ctx.fillText("Myverrynicename", 10, 250)
}

function MyKeyDownHandler(MyEvent) {
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 39 && x_pos + MyImg.width < myCanvas.width) {
    x_pos = x_pos + 7;
  }
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 37 && x_pos > 0) {
    x_pos = x_pos - 7;
  }
}

setInterval(MyTimer, 43);
addEventListener("keydown", MyKeyDownHandler);
```

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title> MD2 </title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id=myCanvas width=456 height=456 style="background-color: green;"> </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you need to use your `x_pos` variable, but you are starting the timer immediately so there's no need to press anything. The `setInterval()` should really be a `setTimeout()` that makes a recursive function call.

```js
// Get DOM references correctly, not by just using the element ID in JavaScript.
// You should use one of the many DOM query methods to get your reference.
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

var x_pos = 0;
var y_pos = 0;
var MyImg = new Image();
MyImg.src = "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/noto-emoji-animals-nature/96/22215-dog-icon.png";

addEventListener("keydown", MyKeyDownHandler);

function MyKeyDownHandler(MyEvent) {
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 39 && x_pos + MyImg.width < myCanvas.width) {
    x_pos += 7;
  }
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 37 && x_pos > 0) {
    x_pos -= 7;
  }
  MyTimer();
}

function MyTimer() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, 456);
  y_pos = y_pos + 1;
  ctx.drawImage(MyImg, x_pos, y_pos);
  ctx.font = "57px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "GainsBoro"
  ctx.fillText("Myverrynicename", 10, 250);
  setTimeout(MyTimer, 43);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title> MD2 </title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="456" height="456" style="background-color: green;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```